# how to convert acronis .tibx new format to .tib old format

Tags: boot, image, acronis

Create an OS image in acronis 2020 with the new .tibx format. The problem is that this image cannot be dumped to an old computer since it does not support Acronis 2020 nor can I use old versions of Acronis Boot Image, because, although it works on old hardware, they do not support the new .tibx format.

How can I convert the image in .tibx format to the old .tib format, to be able to use it in any hardware and with any version of Acronis Boot Image??